# how to add 3 different number to the i, i+1 and i+2 of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know how can I add 3 different number to the 3n, 3n+1 and 3n+2 indices. I mean for example I have following array :

```
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

and then I want add the (3n)th to 5 and then I want add (3n+1)th of an array to 2 and (3n+2) to 3,
I mean the final array I want to be like following result array:

```
var result = [6,3,4,7,4,5,8,5,6]
```

and I try to do it as following code:

```
// arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
 let res = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  res.push([arr[i*3] * 5,
  arr[(i*3)+1] *2,
  arr[(i*3)+2] *3])

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    add = [5,2,3], res=[];
// result = [6,3,4,7,4,5,8,5,6]
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i+=add.length) add.forEach((v,j)=>res[i+j]=arr[i+j]+v);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

An alternative and even shorter solution (similar to @Robin's answer) would be:

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    add = [5,2,3], res=[];

res=arr.map((v,i)=>v+add[i%add.length]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

( I noticed @Nina came up with a very similar answer ...)

Comment: If you want to really accommodate a potentially flexlble array, shouldn't you use `i+=add.length` instead of `i+=3`?

Comment: Well, yes, if that should becaome a requirement, then @Terry's suggestion will be helpful. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), making use of the fact that its function argument takes the current index an optional second argument:

```js
var arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3];

var result = arr.map((num, idx) => {
  switch (idx % 3) {
    case 0:
      return num + 5;
    case 1:
      return num + 2;
    case 2:
      return num + 3;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could mapp the array directly by taking a closure over an index for the values array for adding.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    add = [5, 2, 3],
    result = array.map((i => v => v + add[i++ % add.length])(0));

console.log(...result);
```